# What are some dimension reduction techniques applicable to sparse covariance matrices?

Tags: covariance-matrix, dimensionality-reduction, multivariate-normal-distribution, sparse

Suppose that I have $n\gg 500000$ observations, and I specify
$$\mathbf{y} \sim \text{Normal}(\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma^2_y\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_y + \tau \mathbf{K}\mathbf{K}^T),$$ where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_y$ is a diagonal matrix and $\mathbf{K}$ is a mapping matrix where there are two 1's in each row and 0's elsewhere. When attempting to evaluate this normal density for $\mathbf{y}$, the computation is incredibly slow - and that's with me using the symmetric Woodbury matrix identity. So, I'm wondering what type of dimension reduction techniques may be helpful in this situation, where the covariance matrix for $\mathbf{y}$ is sparse.

Comment: If you're comfortable with numerical linear algebra, an alternative approach to dimension reduction would be to exploit the structure of your matrix to efficiently compute the required log determinant and linear system solve, for example using Krylov subspace methods. See e.g. https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2017/file/976abf49974d4686f87192efa0513ae0-Paper.pdf for this concept applied to gaussian process regressoin.